# How to split AFTER underscore in Python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I've seen a lot of threads that say how to split based on an underscore, but how can we split a string where the split is done after the underscore.

So let's say I have a pandas dataframe with one column:

```
 item
100_5151
101_1205
102_8153
...
```

how can I achieve the following output?

```
  item      id    group
100_5151   100_   5151 
101_1205   101_   1205 
102_8153   102_   8153
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can split on `(?<=_)` like `re.split(r"(?<=_)", "100_5151")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split with the `_` as a separator and then add again the `_` to the id string:

```
id, group =item.split("_")
id=id+"_"
```